# Repeat a set of instruction with while loop - Java

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I am getting user inputs do some calculation and then repeatedly ask the user to take repeatedly until a Sentinel value (3 in my case) entered.

I am using `do-while` loop and it does not give my desired output as shown below,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("1: Addition");
    System.out.println("2: Multiplication");
    System.out.println("3: Exit");

    System.out.print("Please choose a number: ");

    int userinput = input.nextInt();

    // Generate two random numbers
    int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    int number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    do {
        if (userinput == 1) {
            System.out.print("What is " + number1 +  " + " + number2);
            int answer = input.nextInt();
            int tureanswer = number1 + number2;

            if (answer == tureanswer){
                System.out.println("You're correct");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Wrong,correct answer is " + tureanswer);
        }
        if (userinput == 2) {
            System.out.print("What is " + number1 +  " * " + number2 + " : ");
            int answer = input.nextInt();
            int tureanswer = number1 * number2;

            if (answer == tureanswer){
                System.out.println("Correct");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Wrong. The correct answer is "+ tureanswer);
        }   
    }while(userinput !=3);
}
}
```

I am getting the following output,

```
1: Multiplication
2: Addition
3: Exit
Please choose a number: 1
What is 9 + 1  12
Wrong,correct answer is 10
What is 9 + 1
```

However, I need something like this,(prompts the user to select the number not `what is 9 + 1`)

```
1: Addition
2: Multiplication
3: Exit
Please choose a number: 1
What is 9 + 1  12
Wrong,correct answer is 10

1: Addition
2: Multiplication
3: Exit
Please choose a number:
```

What am I doing wrong in my `do` statement? Any thought would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to move `do {` up a few lines.

Only the part between `do {` and `while` gets repeated, and you need that to include asking the user for which type of problem they want, and generating the random numbers.

However, you will need to declare `userInput` **before** `do` if you want to use it as the `while` condition.

```
    int userInput;

    do {
        System.out.print("Please choose a number: ");

        userinput = input.nextInt();

        // Generate two random numbers
        int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        int number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);

        if (userinput == 1) {

           // and so on ...
```

Comment: When I have above user input, I am getting an error `userinput cannot be resolved to a variable`. Also, when I have right above generating random numbers, I am getting the same output as I got before!

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines in your do while

```
System.out.println("1: Multiplication");
System.out.println("2: Addition");
System.out.println("3: Exit");

System.out.print("Please choose a number: ");

int userinput = input.nextInt();
int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
int number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
```

I also suggest you to use switch in do while because it's more practical than if else

Comment: Yes, next, I will try Switch cases for same task! thanks for suggestion!